# In Laravel, how do you bind parameters to a query in query builder DB raw inside another query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two queries that I'm building:

```
$color = \DB::table('colors')->take(10)->orderBy('id', 'desc');

if(isset($between)){
    $color->whereBetween('id', [$start, $end]);
}

$flavor = \DB::table(\DB::raw('(' . $color->toSql() . ') as color'))
               ->join('flavor', 'flavor.color_id', '=', 'color.id')
               ->select('color.id', 'color.name', 'flavor.name');

return $flavor->get();
```

I need to bind 2 values in the first query only IF there is a `$between` set. And it has to be inside that `\DB::raw`.

How do I do that?

P.S if I run the first query separately it works perfectly. But when I try to run the whole query at once I'm getting `General error 2031` (basically the parameters are not bind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try merging the bindings from the first query into the second query before executing it:

```
$flavor->mergeBindings($color);
```

Or just the binding without the 'type' of the bindings:

```
$flavor->addBinding($color->getBindings());
```

The second one should work because you only have a binding for a `where` which is the default type for `addBinding`. For more advanced queries with other bindings you probably want to go the way of merging the bindings so the 'type' of the binding is accurate.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeBindings() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, array given`

Comment: i've used this instead and it works(update the answer with this in it so i can choose it:D): `$flavor->addBinding($color->getBindings());`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change your `DB::table('color')` to your Model name like

```php
Color::take(10)->orderBy('id', 'desc')
```

Secondly, add

```php
->mergeBindings($color->getQuery)
```

Something like this:

```php
use App\Models\Color;
...
$color = Color::take(10)->orderBy('id', 'desc');

if(isset($between)){
    $color->whereBetween('id', [$start, $end]);
}

$flavor = \DB::table(\DB::raw('(' . $color->toSql() . ') as color'))
               ->mergeBindings($color->getQuery())
               ->join('flavor', 'flavor.color_id', '=', 'color.id')
               ->select('color.id', 'color.name', 'flavor.name');


return $flavor->get();
```